# Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion Notation

Tags: inclusion-exclusion

Let $A,B,$ and $C$ be sets such that

$A\subset C, B\subset C$, with $|C|=n$, $|A|=x$, $|B|=y$, and $|A\cap B|=z$.

What is $|C\setminus(A\cup B)|$?

Comment: So exactly which part of your question is about notation?

Comment: I guess notation wasn't the right word, but I'm a little confused about what "C\" means and how the fact that A and B are subsets of C affect the question? I mean, I know that all the elements of A and B are within the set C, so I guess it's really just "C\" confusing me.

Comment: The fact that they're subsets of $C$ affects the question in that it allows the question to be answered. Without this premise, you wouldn't have enough information to determine $|C\setminus(A\cup B)|$.

Comment: It's the relative complement: $C\setminus A=\{x\in C|x\notin A\}$

Comment: So the relative complement between C and $(A\cup B)$ is basically all the elements that are in C but not in $(A\cup B)$?

Comment: @starsaber99: Yes.

Comment: So with regards to the variables given, it would be written as:
$n-(x+y-z)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Inclusion-Exclusion:

$$
|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|=x+y-z.
$$

Now, $C\setminus (A\cup B)$ is the set containing all things in $C$ that are not in the set $A\cup B$. Since $C$ contains $n$ elements, and $A\cup B$ contains $x+y-z$ elements, it follows that

$$
|C\setminus (A\cup B)|=n-(x+y-z)=n+z-x-y.
$$